# Puppeteer: Access fields on login dialog

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to generate a .pdf from a page in our Intranet via Puppeteer / Headless Chrome using Node.js.

Generating a .pdf from a random page is no problem, but I am struggling with our login frame, which appears when opening the page.

It looks like this:

[image: Login]

I can't find a way to access those two fields "Nutzername" and "Passwort" to get logged in because the Developer Tools from Chrome don't show a field name.

The .pdf file or screenshot which gets generated when opening this page always shows "Unauthorized" as if Headless Chrome pressed Abbrechen (Abort) in this dialog.

What I tried so far was like this:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    let url = 'http://intranet...../'
    let browser = await puppeteer.launch()
    let page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'networkidle2' })

    await page.type('#Nutzername', '....'); // Error here, because the identifier is wrong.

    await page.keyboard.press("Tab");

    await page.type('#Passwort', '....');

    await page.type(String.fromCharCode(13)); // Enter

    await page.pdf({
        format:"A4",
        path:'./Speiseplan.pdf',
        displayHeaderFooter: false,
        printBackground:true
    })
    process.exit()
})();
```

Is it not possible to use Puppeteer with those kind of login dialogs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The developer tools in Chrome won't be able to hook these fields because they're not part of the DOM; they're fields that are generated natively by Chromium itself when a server indicates that authentication via [HTTP Basic Authentication](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication#Basic_authentication_scheme) is required.

Fortunately, `puppeteer` resides above both the DOM and the native layers of the Chromium instance it spawns and exposes the [`page.authenticate()`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v3.3.0&show=api-pageauthenticatecredentials) method to use to handle situations like this. Call `page.authenticate()` prior to navigating to the page which asks for Basic Authentication credentials to set the username/password pair to use:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    let url = 'http://intranet...../'
    let browser = await puppeteer.launch()
    let page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.authenticate({'username':'YOUR_BASIC_AUTH_USERNAME', 'password': 'YOUR_BASIC_AUTH_PASSWORD'});
    await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'networkidle2' })

    await page.pdf({
        format:"A4",
        path:'./Speiseplan.pdf',
        displayHeaderFooter: false,
        printBackground:true
    })
    process.exit()
})();
```

[Sony AK on DEV.to](https://dev.to/sonyarianto/puppeteer-quick-tip-how-to-do-basic-authentication-2pe7) has a short-but-sweet article with sample code illustrating `page.authenticate()`'s usage.